# change google map options jquery, center, zoom

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, google-maps

Trying to change some of the options of the current map im holding.
Tried several options:

declaration:

```
$("#map").width("600px").height("350px").gmap3();
```

tried:

```
//not working
$("#map").gmap3({action: 'setOptions', args:[{zoom:7}]});
```

```
//not working
$("#map").gmap3("get", "map").setCenter({
                      getlatlng:{
                        address:  $inputAddress,
                        callback: function(results){
                          if ( !results ) return;
                          $(this).gmap3({
                            marker:{
                              latLng:results[0].geometry.location

                            }
                          });
                        }
                      }
                    });
```

```
//not working
$('#map_canvas').gmap('get','map').setOptions({'center':origin});
```

```
//not working
$('#map').gmap3.panTo(new google.maps.LatLng('0.00','0.00'));
```

Is there any decent documentation of jquery gmaps ? the official one does not cover basic stuff like changing options.
Is there any advantage using gmaps instead of native google maps API via js?
Thanks

Comment: can you do a jsfiddle ?

Comment: im trying, but cant manage to load the gmaps plugin in the fiddle... its located on my pc, cant find the CDN for it.

Answer (score 0):

This will return the `google.maps.Map`-instance in gmap3 V5:

```
$('#map').gmap3('get')
```

to set options use the `setOptions`-method of the Maps-API V3, e.g.:

```
$('#map').gmap3('get').setOptions({center:new google.maps.LatLng(1,1),
                                   zoom:  5});
```